# Как присвоить переменной метод класса

Tags: java, color, awt

Есть такой метод:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

И я хочу, чтобы вместо `Color.red` у меня стояла переменная `color`, к которой я могу получить доступ из любого другого класса и в любой момент изменить цвет.
Есть ли способ присвоить переменной метод `Color.*`?

Comment: Про какой-такой метод идёт речь? `Color.red` - это константа типа `java.awt.Color`, находящаяся в том же классе `java.awt.Color`. Никто вам не запрещает хранить поле `public Color color` и присваивать в него любой цвет. И, конечно, писать `g.setColor(color);`.

Comment: @Regent хорошо, неверно истолковал вопрос, но ответ именно тот, что нужен, но вот каким способом мне в другом классе объявить новый цвет?
Т.е. в классе номер 1, я пишу `public Color color;`
Теперь я пишу `g.setColor(color);`
А каким образом мне изменить цвет в другом классе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Color.red` - это не метод, а константа в файле `Color`. Выглядит она так:

```
public final static Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
```

Соответственно, достаточно просто хранить текущий цвет в поле типа `Color`.

Поэтому добавляем в класс публичный метод для установки цвета, храним установленный цвет в поле и используем его при отрисовке.

В итоге класс выглядит так:

```
public class Entity
{
    private Color color = Color.green;

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

А пользоваться им можно так:

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
entity.setColor(Color.red);
entity.render();
Color newColor = new Color(200, 200, 200);
entity.setColor(newColor);
entity.render();
```

Используя как "стандартные" цвета (например, `Color.red`), так и созданные вручную (например, `new Color(200, 200, 200)`).